# Powering only a part of a circuit

Tags: switches

This is **not** about using two (or more) power sources in a single scheme simultaneously.

My project utilizea CH32V003* MCU. The WCH-Link module and 1-wire serial debug interface (SDI) is used to flash the controller. To update the flash (or debug,) one must connect the Vcc,Vss and SDI wires to appropriate pins of the MCU, then create an artificial brown-out on Vcc. I think there is no straightforward solution (e.g. using optocouplers) to implement galvanically isolated data transfer. My circuit draws current up to 1 A under certain conditions, thus the WCH-Link module could be damaged. To update the flash, everything but the MCU has to be disconnected from the power source.

The connection of two voltage sources simultaneously is prevented by design. Please consider that there is only one source is connected at a time in all the next circuits.
After some considerations, I've came up to the next possible solutions:

1. The simplest

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy0R8U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Pros: the simplest.

Cons: the unpowered MCU could be damaged if Vpower is connected with the switch in the wrong (to missing Vdebug) state.

2. Simple

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa31fS.png)</sup>

Pros: still simple.

Cons: voltage is below 5V. The ADC in the MCU is used; not sure how accurate would be readings.

3. Old school

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcdVAd.png)</sup>

Pros: reliable.

Cons: increased current consumption (in my case does not matter,) takes large size on a PCB.

4. Complex

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOIofk.png)</sup>

Pros: better than #2 in terms of voltage.

Cons: the same as for #2.

Please remember that the components (like 2N5584) are chosen from the list and are not optimal or even suitable. I would like to get a feedback on proposed solutions in general.

Are there any other reasonable methods to power only one part of the circuit?

Comment: `components are chosen from the list` ... is this a school assignment?

Comment: @jsotola no, the list is provided by the Circuitlab. I mean that circuits are not intended for accurate simulations.